# How to insert different values on the same table with new row?

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO registration( name, email, username) values('eswar',(select email from registration),'manikandan')
```

Comment: Why you would want to do that?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: you might want to change `SELECT email FROM registration WHERE name='eswar'`

Comment: just i want to insert two new values and other values are same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is like this:

```
INSERT INTO registration( name, email, username) 
SELECT 'eswar', email, 'manikandan' FROM registration
```

This inserts n lines (the number of lines in the registration table).

To filter this you add a constraint to the select statement.

```
INSERT INTO registration( name, email, username) 
SELECT 'eswar', email, 'manikandan' FROM registration WHERE email="x@yahoo.com"
```

You add the constant values to the SELECT STATEMENT not the other way around.

Comment: this query add all rows. just i want to insert only one row

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use an update query

```
UPDATE registration SET name='eswar', username = 'manikandan' WHERE email = 'email@mail.com'
```